# Filter grid/table data within the selected date range (between two dates)

Tags: angular, syncfusion

I'm using Syncfusion EJ2 Angular UI components.
In this UI i'm using Grid Component to show table data.
Please see the below stackblitz link.

[Grid data with example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sangriddaterange-6vu1gt)

In startdate column i'm not able to filter data with in the selected date range.
Please let me know if any one answer
. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

see below link for answer and it is working.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sangriddaterange?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts